# Why won't this application start when I log in?

Tags: login, autostart

I have a file in `~/.config/autostart/` that looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=python ~/Documents/StackApplet/stackapplet.py
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/stackapplet.png
Terminal=false
Comment=a panel indicator for monitoring StackExchange sites

Name=StackApplet

Categories=Utility;
```

Unfortunately, it isn't working; the application is not starting when I log in. If I open a terminal and copy-and-paste the command listed in `Exec` above, then the application runs just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try expanding the `~/Documents/StackApplet/stackapplet.py` to the full path, using `~` in the path may not be supported in `.desktop` files.

Comment: Well, I'll try it.